# jQuery DataTables Editor trap or handle enter key

Tags: datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

Using [DataTables version 1.10](http://datatables.net/) and [DataTables Editor](http://editor.datatables.net/). We are also using AngularJS.

In the documentation for [submitOnReturn](http://editor.datatables.net/reference/type/form-options#submitOnReturn), the text states:

> Please note that when triggered, this action will call submit()E
>   directly and without any configured options. If you have defined
>   custom actions in a button click handler you would need to either
>   disable this option and replace it with a custom event handler or also
>   listen for the return key event.

We have a custom button function we need to call ($scope.updateQuantity in the code sample below). Is there an example of calling that on an Enter key click?

```
$('#dtProductChildren').on('click', 'tbody td:last-child', function (e) {
    if (product.SomeValue === false) {
        childrenTableEditor.inline(this, 'Quantity', {
            submitOnReturn: false, // what else needs to happen to make this work?
            buttons: { label: 'Update', fn: function () { $scope.updateQuantity(this); } }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What happens with the code you posted currently? I assume that the anonymous function defined for fn is not being called?

Comment: @devhammer yes, it does not get called because that is not how submitOnReturn works. It just calls submit in the DataTables API without any options. Even if I populate the options, I need to call my updateQuantity function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could look for the enter key event and perform your custom action whenever it is detected. I have one instance where I am intercepting the enter key and traversing to another form field (different fields based on where the caret was when detected). This is what I used to get the desired effect:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.onkeypress = function(event) {
        var code = event.keyCode;
        var node = (event.target) ? event.target : ((event.srcElement) ? event.srcElement : null);
        if (node.name == 'serialNumber' && code != null && code == 13) {
            document.getElementById('locationID').focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
});
```

This creates a function that will fire with ***every single keypress*** that checks if the key pressed was an enter. (Which is when code == 13; a bit of a magic number, sorry.)
If you know the name, or other identifying information about the source element, then you could replace the line in my code which adjusts the focus with a call to your update quantity function.